# Why did I get the old restic docker container?

Tags: docker, restic

A year ago I have been playing around with `restic` using the `restic/restic` container. A simple call, like `docker run <etc> restic/restic`. Last week, I finished what I wanted to do with `restic` and I ran into a problem. After quite a bit of searching, I noticed this when I asked `restic/restic` for a version, and it told me:

```
restic 0.15.1 compiled with go1.19.5 on linux/amd64
```

That was old. So, I did a `docker pull` of `restic/restic`, and after that it says:

```
restic 0.16.2 compiled with go1.21.3 on linux/amd64
```

after which, luckily my `restic` problem was gone.

But what I don't understand is why did I get that old container in the first place? Probably, the first time I ran it a year ago, it downloaded that image. But `docker images` did not list it. `docker images -a` does. But why. This is not an 'intermediate image' for which `-a` is intended. What am I missing?